# Automorphism group of algebraic function fields

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, l-functions

Let $K$ be a finite field and let $F/K$ be a function field. Is it possible to deduce the genus of $F/K$ from the automorphism group of $G=Aut(F/K)$?
Is it possible to do so if we know that $|G|$ is greater than the genus?

Comment: Unlikely. There should be many function fields with zero automorphisms.

However, large automorphism groups like $PGL(1)$ could uniquely identify the genus ($0$), like they do in the infinite field case.

Comment: In case of finite fields there are many examples of large genus and large automorphism group like hermitian curve. 